# Preallocate memory for CHOLMOD.Factor

Tags: julia

I have a composite type **foo** with one field **F** that is supposed to store the result of a call to ldltfact().

```
mutable struct foo
   F::Base.SparseArrays.CHOLMOD.Factor{Float64}
end
```

How do I preallocate memory for F to store the result, when I later call:

```
A = rand(4,4)
A = sparse(A*A')
foo.F = ldltfact(A)
```

Comment: Why do you need to pre-allocate here? The allocation will happen when you call `ldltfact(A)` so pre-allocating something inside `foo` seems unnecessary.

Comment: I need to do the factorization a few thousand times and thought that preventing dynamic memory allocation will speed things up!

Comment: In general, `x = y` will not assign `y` to the memory of `x`. If you have the same sparsity pattern for the matrix each time you solve you can use the inplace-version: `ldltfact!(F, A)`, where `F` is the factorization and A the matrix. Look up `ldltfact!` in the documentation: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/linalg/#Base.LinAlg.ldltfact!